# Looping over a dynamic list

Tags: python, loops, dynamic

I would like to make a block of code to make a list that look something like so

```
result = [['a','a','a','a'],
          ['a','a','a','b'],
          ....
```

and so on.

as of yet I try to do it with three list like so.

```
lst = ['a' for x in range(num)]
item_lst = [[None,None] for x in range(num)]
char_lst = string.printable
```

My current plan is to make the item_lst a sort of index of lst where, item_lst[0] is the position in lst, and item_lst[1] is the position in char_lst.

later down in the code there will be a for loop that replaces the character in lst with the the character in char_lst, Based on the instructions of item_lst.

I would like to know if you

A) know of a way to make a loop to complete my ideer

or

B) have a better method of doing it

In the end, the goal would be to make a list with every printable character, in every configuration possible with the given length.

Comment: To me it's not clear what should be the final desired output. Could you please explain better what you want?

Comment: In the end i would like to reach a list where i have ever possible combination of printable character

Comment: You mean you want to filter printable characters from a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is very simple:

```
import itertools
import string

num = 4
result = list(itertools.product(*([string.printable] * num)))
```

However, the list is gonna be **very long**, so this might not be what you want. Specifically, you would have a list with 100000000 elements (with 100 printable elements and `num=4`). You should use generators, not lists:

```
for lst in itertools.product(*([string.printable] * num)):
    # do something with lst
```

Comment: How would i make or get one of those generators, and would it produce the sort of list i need? I'm going to use the result and would need all of the list within it, is this possible for the generator?

Comment: Thank you, it was most defiantly helpful so here you go :D